# Searching through multiple ng-repeats at once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, prestashop

i'm currently working on an application that is build with AngularJS as a base, and that obtains data through the [prestashop webservice](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Web+service+one-page+documentation). All data obtained are `JSON` strings sorted through multiple files. Now i'm trying to create a searchbox that filters through some objects the moment the user fills in the searchbox. The easy way is ofcourse by using the `ng-model` and `filter:` combination like below:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        'Jani',
        'Carl',
        'Margareth',
        'Hege',
        'Joe',
        'Gustav',
        'Birgit',
        'Mary',
        'Kai'
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<p>Type a letter in the input field:</p>

<p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test">
    {{ x }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>


<p>The list will only consists of names matching the filter.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

But what if you're using two different sources? and two different `ng-repeats`?
So in my application some of the data is about customers. The data is obtained through two different `$http.get()` functions. One is for the customers basic information. The second one is the address information. Take a look below:

```
// Get the customers
$http.get('config/get/getCustomers.php', {cache: true}).then(function(response){
    $scope.customers = response.data.customers.customer
});

// Get the addresses
$http.get('config/get/getAddress.php', {cache: true}).then(function (response) {
    $scope.addresses = response.data.addresses.address
});
```

By using `ng-repeat` and `ng-if` i'm able to filter the information and connect it together. `ng-if="customer.id == address.id_customer" ng-repeat=...`

A full example below:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [{
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Jani'
        },{
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'Carl'
        },
        {
        'id': 3,
        'name': 'Tim'
        },
        {
        'id': 4,
        'name': 'Tom'
        }
    ];
    
    $scope.addresses = [{
        'id': 1,
        'id_customer': 1,
        'place': 'Street 12'
        },{
        'id': 2,
        'id_customer': 2,
        'place': 'Other street'
        },
        {
        'id': 3,
        'id_customer': 3,
        'place': 'marioworld!'
        },
        {
        'id': 4,
        'id_customer': 4,
        'place': 'Space!'
        }
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="namesCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="customer in customers">
        <div ng-bind="customer.id + ' - ' + customer.name"></div>
        <div ng-if="customer.id == address.id_customer" ng-repeat="address in addresses" ng-bind="address.place">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So as you can see i'm able to create the combination with the `ng-if` but now i would like to create a search input that's able to search through both fields. And that's where my issue starts. I'm able to create it for one ng-repeat. But what if i want to Search on the address and the customer? I would like to create the possibility of letting the user search by customer name, street address and ZIP code. But the ZIP code and address are from a different source.

I hope that someone has found a solution for this and if you have any questions please ask them in the comments.

As always, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to map your customers array adding to each object it's own place this way:

```
$scope.customers.map( function addPlace(item) {
   item.place = $scope.addresses.reduce(function(a,b){
       return item.id === b.id_customer ? b.place : a;
   }, '');
   return item;
})
```

This way your template will be easier to read, and you will be able to use your previous search.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [{
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Jani'
        },{
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'Carl'
        },
        {
        'id': 3,
        'name': 'Tim'
        },
        {
        'id': 4,
        'name': 'Tom'
        }
    ];
    
    $scope.addresses = [{
        'id': 1,
        'id_customer': 1,
        'place': 'Street 12'
        },{
        'id': 2,
        'id_customer': 2,
        'place': 'Other street'
        },
        {
        'id': 3,
        'id_customer': 3,
        'place': 'marioworld!'
        },
        {
        'id': 4,
        'id_customer': 4,
        'place': 'Space!'
        }
    ];

    $scope.customers.map( function addPlace(item) {
       item.place = $scope.addresses.reduce(function(a,b){
           return item.id === b.id_customer ? b.place : a;
       }, '');
       return item;
    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="namesCtrl">

  <p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>
  <div ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:test">
        {{ customer.id }} - {{ customer.name }}
        <br>
        {{ customer.place}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly where i was looking for, sorry for the late response (:

Comment: I've tried a second attempt. In wich i need to filter through multiple objects. But i get an error returned saying: `angular.js:14516 TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined` But in the same `app.js` inside another controller, using it for customers it does work the way it should? Do you maybe know how this can happen?

Comment: reduce is a javascript built in function for array object. Check your object type because you are probably trying to use it on something different :)