# TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

So my question may come up as a bit weird but the problem i'm having is actually very strange aswell.

So for creating custom search filters i'm using `javascript`'s function of `.map` and `.reduce` in this case i'm using these in my scope examples. Take a look at the following code:

```
$http.get('config/get/getOrders.php', {cache: true}).then(function(response){
        $scope.orders = response.data.orders.order;
        $scope.orders.map( function addPlace(item) {
            item.firstname = $scope.customers.reduce(function(a,customers){
                return item.id_customer === customers.id ? customers.firstname : a;
            }, '');
            return item;
        });
    });
```

So in the `$http.get()` i'm requesting a JSON file with data. This data consists of some orders with information. All these orders have a `id_customer` value. This value is connects to the customer information whom placed the order.

So i wanted to widen my search function with that `customer name` For more information about how and why take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325547/searching-through-multiple-ng-repeats-at-once) i've asked yesterday.

And it worked. The filter could also search the `customer_firstname`. But then i wanted to use the same type of function in another controller. The function goal stays the same. Connecting data from multiple `$scope` types. But weird as it is the return is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined`. Yes i've placed this in the same app.js, but just in another controller. i've checked if all the data of `$scope.products` and `$scope.stock_availables` and `$scope.productCombiantions` exists and it does, i've checked the providers and etc and all suits fine to me so i have no clue why this is happening. The function in this case is:

```
$http.get('config/get/getProducts.php', {cache: true}).then(function(response){
    $scope.products = response.data.products.product;
    $scope.products.map( function addPlace(item) {
        item.eanCombination = $scope.productCombinations.reduce(function(a, productCombinations, stock_availables){
            return item.id === stock_availables.id + stock_availables.id === stock_availables.id_product_attribute + stock_availables.id_product_attribute === productCombinations.id ? productCombinations.ean13: a;
        }, '');
        return item;
    });
});
```

**Short summary:** A function does work in one controller but the same function doesn't work in another controller.

If you have any questions please ask them in the comments.

As always, Thanks in advance!

Comment: There could be some race condition caused by some async calls where `$scope.productcombinations` gets recreated/reassigned at some point before calling `.reduce`. However, this is just a guess at this point since I don't know what the rest of your related code is doing.

Comment: No, but i've already found the error. It did have to do with the sequence in wich everything is called. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i made a mistake in the sequence in wich all data is loaded. Because of the fact that the `$scope.productCombinations` was loaded after the products sequence. So tip for everyone. Always check the sequence in wich your code is written.

Comment: Also, be careful when working with multiple promises at a time where the data could be dependent, knowing that they could be resolved in an unpredictable order. You have to use the chaining properly to make sure you're accessing data in a spot where you know its promise would have been resolved.