# Using array .map and $scope.__.reduce() for advanced angularjs filters

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, function

i'm currently building some advanced filters to use in a search input. I'm trying to search through multiple `JSON` objects at once. I've been able to use the functions `.map` and `.reduce` to create these filters. For more information look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325547/searching-through-multiple-ng-repeats-at-once) that gave me this solution to work with. So for the `orders` page i've been able to add the customer firstname through this function. Take a look at the code below:

```
$http.get('config/get/getOrders.php', {cache: true}).then(function(response){
        $scope.orders = response.data.orders.order;
        $scope.orders.map( function addPlace(item) {
            item.firstname = $scope.customers.reduce(function(a,customers){
                return item.id_customer === customers.id ? customers.firstname : a;
            }, '');
            return item;
        });
    });
```

by using `$scope.orders.map()` and `$scope.customers.reduce()` i'm able to add a value to the `orders` array. By doing this i'm able to extend my search filter with the `customer_name`.

The problem i'm having now is actually two different things. The first thing is that i'm trying to create a more advanced comparison before obtaining one item. (The `Combination_product_code`) Take a look at the code below:

```
$http.get('config/get/getProducts.php', {cache: true}).then(function(response){
    $scope.products = response.data.products.product;
    $scope.products.map( function addPlace(item) {
        item.eanCombination = $scope.productCombinations.reduce(function(a, productCombinations, stock_availables){
            return item.id === stock_availables.id + stock_availables.id === stock_availables.id_product_attribute + stock_availables.id_product_attribute === productCombinations.id ? productCombinations.ean13: a;
        }, '');
        return item;
    });
});
```

So as you can see i need to check through multiple values before i'm able to obtain the `ean13` sadly this isn't working and i'm wondering if i'm setting the comparison right? i've checked all the value names multiple times and they are correct.

The second issue is adding multiple new items. I've been trying to add a product_name but also the products reference code. Take a look at the code below:

```
$http.get('config/get/getStock.php', {cache: true}).then(function (response) {
    $scope.stock_availables = response.data.stock_availables.stock_available;
    $scope.stock_availables.map( function addPlace(item) {
        item.product_name = $scope.products.reduce(function(a,products){
            return item.id_product === products.id ? products.name.language : a;
        },
        item.product_reference = $scope.products.reduce(function(b,products) {
            return item.id_product === products.id ? products.reference: b;
        }));
        return item;
    });
});
```

So my issues are adding multiple comparison queries before obtaining and adding the item and adding multiple items.

**Update:**

I've solved my issue about the "adding multiple items." The mistake i've made was in closing the function correctly. A working example:

```
$http.get('config/get/getStock.php', {cache: true}).then(function (response) {
    $scope.stock_availables = response.data.stock_availables.stock_available;
    $scope.stock_availables.map( function addPlace(item) {
        item.product_name = $scope.products.reduce(function(a,products){
            return item.id_product === products.id ? products.name.language : a;
        }),
        item.product_reference = $scope.products.reduce(function(b,products) {
            return item.id_product === products.id ? products.reference: b;
        });
        return item;
    });
});
```

This means that i'm looking for a solution about using multiple comparison queries before obtaining the data.

The workflow for this data is:

i'm using `ng-repeat="product in products"` within the products data i'm creating a filter that corresponds to the following data:

Products table:
id,
Name,
price,
etc,

stock table:
id,
**product_id,**
quantity,
**product_attribute_id,**

Combinations table:
id -> "Corresponds with attribute_id from stock table",
**combinationEAN** -> "The value i'm trying to reach",

So the workflow is:

```
Stock table -> id_product from products table -> combination id -> attribute_id from stock table.
```

I'm able to filter this within my view by using:

```
<h5 ng-if="combination.id >= 1 && product.id == stock_available.id_product && stock_available.id_product_attribute == combination.id" ng-repeat="combination in productCombinations" ng-bind="combination.ean13"></h5>
```

What i would like to to do is add that `combination.ean13` directly to the `products` `$scope` by using the example above. So that i'm able to use a search input to search for that value and only show those products. See the example below:

```
<input type="text" class="bc-f3f3f3 form-control no-border" ng-model="productSearch" ng-change="filterProduct(productSearch)" placeholder="{{ 'Zoek of scan producten' | translate }}">

<div ng-infinte-scroll="loadMore()" infinite-scroll-disabled='products.busy' infinite-scroll-distance='1' class="align-center tcolor-2a95cf text-center padding-t-25 padding-s-45 no-margin row">
    <div  class="productimg col-4" ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy: '-date_add' | filter: filterProduct(productSearch) | filter: {id_category_default: productCategory}">
        <div class="out-of-stock" ng-if="product.id == stock_available.id_product && stock_available.quantity == 0 && stock_available.id_product_attribute == 0" ng-repeat="stock_available in stock_availables">
            <div class="stock-circle"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img ng-value="{{reference}}"  data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-sm{{product.id}}"  ng-value="{{ean13}}" alt="{{product.name.language}}" ng-src="{{settings.url}}/{{product.id_default_image}}-home_default/{{product.link_rewrite.language}}.jpg" err-src="{{settings.url}}//img/p/nl-default-home_default.jpg" class="img-responsive product-img"/>
            <p ng-bind="product.name.language"></p>
            <p ng-bind="product.eanCombination"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

// Controller:
    $http.get('config/get/getProducts.php', {cache: true}).then(function(response){
        $scope.products = response.data.products.product;
        $scope.products.map( function addPlace(item) {
            item.eanCombination = $scope.productCombinations.reduce(function(a, productCombinations, stock_availables){
                return item.id === stock_availables.id_product + stock_availables.id_product === stock_availables.id_product_attribute + stock_availables.id_product_attribute === productCombinations.id ? productCombinations.ean13: a;
            }, '');
            return item;
        });
    });


    $scope.filterProduct = function(productSearch) {
        return (name.language = productSearch) || (ean13 = productSearch) || (reference = productSearch) || (eanCombination = productSearch);
    };
```

If you have any questions please ask them in the comments below.

As always, thanks in advance!

Comment: Using `map()` incorrectly. It returns a new array but you don't assign that new array to any variable. Seems you are just using it as a `forEach`

Comment: why not use `Array.prototype.filter()` for what it does: return the element if the callback returns true?

Comment: @cowbert Because that immediately filters the items, but i'm searching for a way to add it to the existing source. If i'm wrong, could you show me an example of how to establish this?

Comment: all of the array iterator functions support passing a reference to the originating array as the 3rd argument in the callback signature: `var newarr = arr.filter(function(element, index, src_arr) { src_arr  === arr })`